# Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) is not returning UTC time

Tags: java

I am really confused with the result I am getting with `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` method call, it's returning IST time.

Here is the code I used

```
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime());
```

and the response I got is:

```
Sat Jan 25 15:44:18 IST 2014
```

So I tried changing the default TimeZone to UTC and then I checked, then it is working fine

```
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime());

TimeZone tz  = TimeZone.getDefault() ;
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar cal_Three = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal_Three.getTime());
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
```

Result:

```
Sat Jan 25 16:09:11 IST 2014
Sat Jan 25 10:39:11 UTC 2014
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The `System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime())` invocation returns a `Date` from `getTime()`. It is the `Date` which is getting converted to a string for `println`, and that conversion will use the default `IST` timezone in your case.

You'll need to explicitly use `DateFormat.setTimeZone()` to print the `Date` in the desired timezone.

EDIT: Courtesy of @Laurynas, consider this:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
       new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

System.out.println("Time zone: " + timeZone.getID());
System.out.println("default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("UTC:     " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("Default: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for a moment. Maybe the title isn't explicit enough ?
By the way, thanks for the help

Comment: You can save use a lot of time if you show the result of System.out.println :)

Comment: I get this.. thanks.. But I don't understand how setting a timezone setting would be the responsibility of simpleDateFormat class. Changing the timezone changes the actual time, not it's format. SimpleDateFormat's job is to just format the date, not manipulate the time....

Comment: Perfect Answer !!

Comment: This (having to set the formatter's timezone) gets me every time, even though I set the calendar's timezone.

Answer (score 22):

`java.util.Date` is independent of the timezone. When you print `cal_Two` though the `Calendar` instance has got its timezone set to `UTC`, `cal_Two.getTime()` would return a `Date` instance which does not have a timezone (and is always in the default timezone)

```
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime());
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTimeZone());
```

**Output:**

```
 Sat Jan 25 16:40:28 IST 2014
    sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

From the javadoc of `TimeZone.setDefault()`

> Sets the TimeZone that is returned by the getDefault method. If zone
>   is null, reset the default to the value it had originally when the VM
>   first started.

Hence, moving your `setDefault()` before `cal_Two` is instantiated you would get the correct result.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime());

Calendar cal_Three = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal_Three.getTime());
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jan 25 11:15:29 UTC 2014
Sat Jan 25 11:15:29 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 11):

You are definitely missing a small thing and that is you are not setting a default value:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

So the code would look like:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime());
```

**Explanation**: If you want to change the time zone, set the default time zone using `TimeZone.setDefault()`

Comment: Any idea why setDefault is required first?

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
currentTime.set(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").getRawOffset());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendar.getTimeInMillis()
```

is working for me

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     Following code is the simple example to change the timezone
> ```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          //get time zone
          TimeZone timeZone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo");
          Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
          //setting required timeZone
          calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone1);
          System.out.println("Time :" + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

       }
```

> if you want see the list of timezones, here is the follwing code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (String id : ids) {
        System.out.println(displayTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id)));
    }

    System.out.println("\nTotal TimeZone ID " + ids.length);

}

private static String displayTimeZone(TimeZone tz) {

    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tz.getRawOffset());
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tz.getRawOffset())
                              - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    // avoid -4:-30 issue
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes);

    String result = "";
    if (hours > 0) {
        result = String.format("(GMT+%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    } else {
        result = String.format("(GMT%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.

Get in Timestamp type:

```
public static Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    return ts;
}
```

Get in String type:

```
    public static String getCurrentTimestamp() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    return ts.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Try to use `GMT` instead of `UTC`. They refer to the same time zone, yet the name `GMT` is more common and might work.

Comment: Using GMT will produce the same results.