# Scala TimeZone Issue

Tags: java, scala, timezone

I am facing this issue, I set the timezone to `UTC` but it still Says IST.

```
>>> import java.util.Calendar
>>> import java.util.TimeZone
>>> val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
>>> cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
>>> cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()
res95: String = Coordinated Universal Time  # here i got UTC
>>> cal.getTime()
res97: java.util.Date = Thu Oct 08 13:13:17 IST 2015
                                            ^^^   
                                    why here IST insted of UTC???
```

Comment: possbile duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349475/calendar-getinstancetimezone-gettimezoneutc-is-not-returning-utc-time

Answer (score 4):

The 'getTime' function returns you a java Date object, which does not have knowledge of the `setTimeZone` call you made to the Calendar object. the Date object has no concept of timezone, it is just a wrapper around milliseconds since the epoch. The output you're seeing is just the default `toString` representation used by the Scala REPL to describe the object. You can explicitly convert a Date object to String in a specific timezone using code such as the following:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{TimeZone, Date}

val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
val date= new Date(1444291567242l); //java.util.Date = Thu Oct 08 09:06:07 BST 2015
val dateString = formatter.format(date); //String = 2015-10-08 08:06:07 UTC
```