# Time conversion through browser offset

Tags: java, timezone

I am using browser offset time to convert a given time to local time. Here is the code I am using for converting time from atlantic timezone(-4:00) to IST.

```
int hours=23;
int mins =30;
Calendar date=Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);  
browserOffsetTime=-browserOffsetTime;
TimeZone defaultTZ=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Bermuda");
int serverTimeOffset=defaultTZ.getRawOffset()+defaultTZ.getDSTSavings();
Date GMTDate= new Date(date.getTimeInMillis() - serverTimeOffset);
Date userBrowserTime = new Date(GMTDate.getTime() + browserOffsetTime);
Calendar cal1=Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(userBrowserTime);
```

This code returns exact result for EST which is 10:00 AM where as it returns 8:00 AM which should be 9:00 AM.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21349556/3739916 this code returns exact results for both the time zones. But I need to work this out using browser offset time.

Comment: Could there be a daylight savings issue to explain the one hour discrepancy?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I checked it without adding daylight savings, still the results are same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I didn't understand you immediately. So, should I not use browser offset time for time conversions?

Comment: No, quite the opposite, you need to use browser's offset, this is the only way to get the offset of your client.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several common mistakes:

- You've got a fixed offset that you obtained from the browser - probably through JavaScript code like `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`.  That would be the offset from UTC for the client *at the current date and time*.  You cannot just apply this offset to any arbitrary timestamp, as the client's offset may be different depending on which point in time you are asking for.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824) for how to guess at the user's actual time zone.
- You're doing a lot of manual manipulation of timestamps and offsets through addition and subtraction.  This sort of code should be avoided unless you're authoring a date/time library.  Java has many good options, such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for Java 7 and earlier, and [the built-in `java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for Java 8 and newer.  You should avoid using the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` APIs, as there are *many* challenges with these.
- When you do something like `new Date(timestamp + offset)` - you aren't actually performing a time zone conversion.  Everything that interacts with the `java.util.Date` object is expecting that the timestamp is based on the Unix Epoch, which is explicitly in terms of UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).  So if you add or subtract an offset, *you're just picking a different instant in time*.  If you use the newer APIs, you will not have to think about this.
- You are computing `serverTimeOffset` as the base offset + the DST bias, but you aren't considering whether or not DST is in effect.  If you use the newer APIs, you will not have to think about this either.