# How to get the timezone offset in UTC (like UTC+07:00) from a physical device?

Tags: android, time, timezone, timezone-offset

How to get the timezone offset in UTC (like `UTC+03:00`) from Android device? I'm able to retrieve timezone offset in GMT format (which looks like `GMT+03:00`) with help of this code:

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)
```

by I can't to retrieve timezone offset in UTC format (what I want actually retrieve is something like `UTC+03:00`). How to achieve this?

**UPD**

It seems that it's something wrong with `java.util.TimeZone` class, because

```
val timeZoneGMT = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
Log.d("OLOLO ","Time zone GMT: " + timeZoneGMT.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT))
```

outputs

> Time zone GMT: GMT+00:00

but at the same time

```
val timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
Log.d("OLOLO ","Time zone UTC: " + timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT))
```

outputs just this:

> Time zone UTC: UTC

Comment: Solution for all android versions is addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21349556/2199894

Comment: @BasselMourjan, thanks, but this question about returning UTC time. And I need exactly UTC offset, rather than time in UTC format...

Comment: in that case another simple solution comes to mind.. string.replace() to replace GMT with UTC.. since both are the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Using `java.time`

```
    long timeNow = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toEpochSecond();
    Log.d("Time ","Three years ago: " 
            + NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(timeNow));
```

**NOTE: for this your minimum API level must be 19 or above.**

Using `Calender`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Log.d("Time ",sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

**NOTE:- This would work in all API level.**

Hope it will solve your problem.